Visual Studio 2015, 2017 & 2019 is extremely slow during forms design
I recently started developing software for a company. However, after replacing my entire setup with (Lenovo P16s laptop with RTX A500, 32" Lenovo monitors and Lenovo docking station) I started having performance issues with Visual Studio (only when designing any form), specifically in versions 2015, 2017 and 2019.
Curiously, it only happened when I moved the Visual Studio window to one of my external monitors connected through the Docking Station, but if I use it on the laptop integrated monitor with or without the docking station connected, it worked perfectly.
I tried everything, updating Windows drivers, modifying Visual Studio options, update nvidia drivers, modify Windows registry, reinstalling the Win 10 and Win 11 OS, BIOS update, Docking Firmware Update, I searched support forums for Lenovo, Microsoft, Nvidia, and many more things but the problem persists.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The only thing I hadn't tried was to modify the resolution of the screens, but I didn't see it as logically possible, so I checked my Windows display settings and I detected the resolution of my external monitors was set to 2560x1440, and the integrated monitor of my laptop was set to 3840x2400, so I decided to lower the resolution of the integrated monitor of my laptop to 2560x1600 for test and opened Visual Studio 2015 again, moved it to one of my external monitors connected through the docking station and it worked!!!, the slowness disappeared!!!, this was my solution.
